# Problemas con Carrusel de Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-5

Estoy intentando hacer un carrusel, y me muestra la imagen por unos microsegundos solo cuando recargo la página y luego desaparece.
No sé si lo estoy inicializando correctamente o no, estoy aprendiendo y no entiendo. Sigo tutoriales de youtube y nada.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <script src="./assets/nav_include.js"></script>
    </header>


    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="../styles/media/conectaamunddo.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="../styles/media/conectaamunddo.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="../styles/media/conectaamunddo.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<script src="../views/assets/carrusel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```javascript
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#carouselExampleSlidesOnly');
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel);
```

Comment: El código como texto y formateado como código, tienes las herramientas de edición. No va como imágenes.

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @padaleiana gracias, ya he modificado mi pregunta

Comment: Ten presente que cuando estás importando _bootstrap.bundle.min.js_, de por sí ya estás importando _bootstrap.min.js_ + _popper.min.js_.

Comment: @padaleiana esa era una de las dudas que tenía, ya lo modifiqué, pero sigo con el error que describo anteriormente, cuando recargo la página aparece la imagen como si fuese un pestañeo y ya, no me aparece nada más

Comment: ¿Qué tienen los scripts _carrusel.js_ y _nav_include.js_? Hice las pruebas con imágenes _dummy_ (como por ejemplo [con esta URL](https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=aaa)) y carga sin problemas. Funciona el carrusel correctamente.